# PHP: Text transformed after being put in database

Tags: php, database, encoding, character, cpu-word

I have a form sending data to a mySQL database. But when I enter some text like "Jack&Jones", the special characters get transformed into HTML special chars (here, the & becomes "`&amp;`").

The data inserted in this database can later be used to generate Word documents using a template, but these HTML characters are read wrong and the resulting file is completely messed up.

I tried to resolve the problem by ensuring all my pages used the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` tag and by using `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` to ensure that the data keeps the UTF-8 encoding during the whole process, but it did not work.

So my question is: how do I ensure the encoding consistency between my form, my database and my word document ?

Comment: You need to ensure that UTF-8 is passed in the db connection also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['your_field'], ENT_QUOTES)
```

for text decode

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it will helps to you: 
For Decode text :

```
   htmlspecialchars("Jack&Jones", ENT_QUOTES);
```

For Decode the text like below, than you can use below :

```
   <?php
      $str = "This is some &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; text.";
     echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
   ?>
```